# Replacing the Root site with Intranet site

Tags: sharepoint-online, spo

So I am testing a scenario where there was a old team site as root site at first and then there was a intranet site (Hub site) set up with hub site nav and audience targeting to show as per their permissions.

To replace the root site i have de resisted the hub site for intranet site and then replaced the old root site (Team site) with the new intranet site and then resisted as hub site but now i see that hub site navigation is changed to site level navigation instead of showing the navigation in hub

My question is how we can get back to hub navigation instead of seeing the old navigation
and also site no longer shows the extened header and header image.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your description, I understand that you have a team site A and a hub site B. You unregistered the hub site B, the hub site B has become a team site C. Then you register the team site A as a sub site. The original hub navigation of hub site B has become site level navigation in the team site C. You want site level navigation in the team site C to go back to hub navigation. And you also want to extend header and header image never show in the team site C. If it is wrong, please correct me.

1.If you want to go back to hub navigation, you should re-register the team site C as a hub site again.

2.If you want to extend header and header image never show in the team site C, you should remove header image and change header setting in the “Change and look”.

Comment: No Let me explain it clearly So i have Site A (Team Site) which is already a root site in the tenant and i have Site B which is a HUB site and a intranet site so when Site B was made a Root site the Hub navigation of the hub site became the site level navigation.

Comment: What is the meaning of "root site"? Top-level site or start page?

Comment: Root site is always a domain.sharepoint.com